# JQuery calling .elements returns undefined

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, arrays, checkbox

I'm trying to loop through a group of checkboxes using jQuery. The checkboxes are written in HTML as such:

```
<div id="checkboxes">
    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" name="XXX" class="custom-control-input" id="a" value="XXX">
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="a">XXX</label>
    </div>
    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" name="XXX" class="custom-control-input" id="b" value="XXX">
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="b">XXX</label>
    </div>
    ...
</div>
```

I attempt to get an array of the checkboxes in JQuery with this (part of a response to a button click):

```
var choices = document.getElementById("checkboxes").elements;
```

However, when I call `for(let i = 0; i < choices.length; i++)`, I get an error in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

Apparently, the variable `choices` is undefined. I've done some research, but I can't find where the problem is or another way I can get an array of the checkbox elements.

Comment: Where is your code that attempts to get the length of `choices`? Also, `document.getElementById()` is plain JS, not jQuery.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I edited it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to target the specific collection of elements

```js
var choices = document.querySelectorAll('#checkboxes input[type="checkbox"]');

choices.forEach( el => console.log(el.id, el.value) )
```

```html
<div id="checkboxes">
    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" name="XXX" class="custom-control-input" id="a" value="XXX">
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="a">XXX</label>
    </div>
    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" name="XXX" class="custom-control-input" id="b" value="XXX">
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="b">XXX</label>
    </div>
    
</div>
```